# Android SQLite get data from database to an array

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to get the value from the cursor without the SimpleCursorAdapter part.here is the code

```
public Cursor queueAll(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1, KEY_CONTENT2,KEY_CONTENT3};
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
    null, null, null, null, null);
  return cursor;
 }
```

and the activity side code

```
cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

       from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3};
       int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3};
       cursorAdapter =
       new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
       listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter); 

       while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
       {
           String tilt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1));
           String pkg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3));
           if(tilt.equals("LEFT"))
           {
           Log.v("LEFT",pkg);
           }
           else if(tilt.equals("RIGHT"))
           {
               Log.v("RIGHT",pkg);
           }
           cursor.moveToNext();
       }
```

i am getting the pkg value correct.but i want to get the values directly from the cursor while removing SimpleCursorAdapter part the code doesn't work.
any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Its not clear what you are looking for here.

Comment: i want to get the values from the cursor.but without this piece of code                                                            from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT2, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3};
       int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3};
       cursorAdapter =
       new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
       listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

Comment: you have to call cursor.moveToFirst() before entering the loop. (or use the result from moveToNext() as your exit condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get values without declaring adapters. Adapters are need if you want to show the data in the list widgets. So your can be the following:

```
cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

if (cursor == null) {
//check if there are errors or query just return null
}
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
       {
           String tilt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1));
           String pkg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT3));
           if(tilt.equals("LEFT"))
           {
           Log.v("LEFT",pkg);
           }
           else if(tilt.equals("RIGHT"))
           {
               Log.v("RIGHT",pkg);
           }
           cursor.moveToNext();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must count how many rows are in your table. Then assign that count to variable and it use to create an array. For array size you can use that count variable. Then create a for loop and  use that count variable for rounds. After create your query and assign values to your arrays. 100% worked!.

```
    int sqlcount;
    Cursor mFetch;

    SQLiteDatabase mydb = openOrCreateDatabase("your database name", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    mydb.execSQL("create table if not exists customer(name varchar,email varchar)");
    Cursor mCount = mydb.rawQuery("select count(*) from customer", null);
    mCount.moveToFirst();
    sqlcount = mCount.getInt(0);
    mCount.close();

    String cname[] = new String[sqlcount];
    String cemail[] = new String[sqlcount];


     for(int i=0;i<sqlcount;i++) {

          mFetch= mydb.rawQuery("select name,email from customer", null);
          mFetch.moveToPosition(i);

          cname[i] = mFetch.getString(0);
          cemail[i] = mFetch.getString(1);


     }

     mFetch.close();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(cname[0]),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(cemail[1]),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```